# getting of a menuitemfont in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i have a ccmenuitemfont and its contained inside a ccsprite. . 
the touch event is assigned to menuitemfont.. i need to get the reference of the ccsprite which contains the menuitemfont on ccmenuitemfont click... that is i need to get the reference of the parent sprite.. how to implement? any ideas ? the code i used is as follows..

CCSprite *ballSprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:imageName];
    [ballSprite setTag:randomNumber];

```
CCMenuItem *labelButton=[CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",randomNumber]target:self selector:@selector(clickedBallLabel :)];
[labelButton setTag:randomNumber];
CCMenu *ball=[CCMenu menuWithItems:labelButton, nil];
[ball setPosition:ccp([ballSprite boundingBox].size.width/2, [ballSprite boundingBox].size.height/2)];
[ballSprite addChild:ball];
[self addChild:ballSprite];
[ballSprite setPosition:randomStartPoint];
id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5 position:ccp(randomX, -30)];
[ballSprite runAction:move];
```

Answer (score 0):

in my point of view , there is a logic problem in you program,you want your labelbutton have a recation right? when your touch it,so why you need a reference to parent with the button?but if there is a must for sure ,you need a   spritesheet like this :
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"scene1atlas.plist"];
            spriteBatchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"scene1atlas.png"];

then you can add your obj into the batchnode,after that you can use [obj parent] get the parent reference

i'm not sure i know what your meaning,when the button been touched,the ballsprite should be changed?if so,you can just change the ballsprite directly for another new sprite,of course,the better way is the sprites should be into one batchnode as much as possible, otherwise,if your ballsprite is a spritesheet ,then use the method i've told before

Comment: ya i need the reference .... bcoz on clicking the button label.. i need to change the image of the sprite that holds the buttonlabel.. so any way to get the reference for sprite or pls help me with any other implementation logic